# Trying to add a scene in the video editing mode I get "No Items Available" [Blender 2.8]

Tags: 3d-view, video-sequence-editor, video, scene

I'm trying to add a scene created in the 3D viewport to the video editor.. this works in Blender 2.79, but in Blender 2.8 it doesn't work.

When I try to add a scene created in the 3D viewport to the video editor (video editing mode -> add -> scene) it appears "No Items Available".

P.S. I know that I can do the same by adding directly a text in the video editing mode.. I'm just adding a text here to make it easier to understand.

[image: 3D Viewport Blender 2.8]
[image: No Items Available]
[image: Adding a text Blender 2.79]
[image: Scene]
[image: Added without any problem]

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

You just need to add a new scene and add to the new scene the text instead of adding text in the default scene. 
Once done that if you go to video editing mode -> add -> scene you will see the new scene appearing as an option.